# Gradle config for ContentProvider contract

Tags: android, gradle, contract, artifact

I'm trying to make separate artifact in my project to build jar file with ContentProvider contract classes. To build this jar I use next task:

```
task contractsJar(type: Jar) {
  from android.applicationVariants.release.javaCompile.destinationDir
  includes "contract classes filter"
  into "$buildDir/libs"
}

contractsJar.dependsOn 'compileReleaseJava'
```

but this task build jar with base path in the system root (for Mac OS X it is `/Users/myuser...`). So what should I do to make "right" jar with base path in the project root?

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

1. android.applicationVariants.release doesn't exist at the very beginning, so we should use `DomainObjectCollection.all()`
2. `into` works in some weird way - if we use it then jar will have system root as base folder

So the result config:

```
task contractsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'compileReleaseJava')

android.applicationVariants.all() { variant ->
  if (variant.name == "release") {
    contractsJar {
      from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
      include "filter pattern (ANT style)"
      baseName="contracts"
    }
  }
}
```